# Hibernate referenced @MapKey

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to map an map collection, which use key from referenced table?
Its hard for explaining, so here is an example of what I want to accomplish. I want to have map in Type entity from language code (String) to TypeLang entity.

```
@Entity
public class Type {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "type")
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "language.code")
    private Map<String, TypeLang> langMap;
}

@Entity
public class TypeLang {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id")
    private Type type;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "lang_code")
    private Language language;
}

@Entity
public class Language {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "code")
    @GeneratedValue
    private String code;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MapKeyJoinColumn is used if you want your Key to be an Entity. To use String you have to use the MapKeyColumn annotation.